# Not able to do recording of java desktop application using LoadRunner 2021

Tags: loadrunner

We are getting error as No Class Found during the recording of the java windows application through load-runner 2021.

Below are our steps :-

Java Record Replay ---->Executable/Batch ----> Start Recording

Attached is the error screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See Java Template.   Use the source, Luke